# Debian Jessie bleeding edge install whilst retaining system packages

Tags: python, linux, numpy, upgrade, apt-get

I'm using spaCy which requires a much newer version of python-numpy than the system version provided by Debian Jessie. So I remove numpy using apt-get and install new versions using pip and pip3. But removing the system numpy removes my terminator (nice terminal app for Debian). I use this application all the time so I don't want it to disappear? Is there a way to retain the system version of numpy and also use a new version of numpy with spaCy? I don't want to use virtual machines. Is there a way to use virtualenv or some other tool to do this?

Comment: AFAIK You shouldn't be touching your system Python like that. Install a dedicated interpreter for your own stuff. Make use of virtual environments, or `conda` environments.

Comment: I've used conda before but its very heavy weight and runs out of space. But maybe that is me being too lazy. Is there a more light weight way than docker and conda? I suppose my dilemma is that all this stuff from pip and pip3 is going into /usr/local/ so why can't they coexist nicely?

Comment: I thought that the File Hierarchy System (FHS) was supposed to sort all these problems out. If you wanted binaries in /usr/local or /opt rather than /usr you just flipped the switch (Malkovich style!)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Pin your package. Off-topic here, already discussed on [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Can you point me to the solution on Super User? That way a few people can mark it as a duplicate and I'll just close the question.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a nice way of doing what the FHS should be doing by default. I can download the very latest pip3 version and install all recent packages in a way that will keep them separated from the rest of the OS (as /usr/local should be doing, but doesn't do!!!). I've included the spaCy installation as an example:

```
virtualenv -p python3 ~/bleeding-edge-virtualenv
source ~/bleeding-edge-virtualenv/bin/activate
mkdir -p python/workspaces && cd python/workspaces
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -O ./get-pip.py
python3 ./get-pip.py
python3 --version
pip 9.0.1 from /home/ekenny/bleeding-edge-virtualenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages (python 3.4)
git clone https://github.com/explosion/spaCy
cd spaCy
pip3 download -m requirements.txt 
pip3 install -r requirements.txt 
python3 setup.py install
deactivate
```

Then I can remove all the crud under /usr/local and never have to worry about duplicate stuff. Full bleeding edge environment loadable at any time using **activate**. Happy days.